# Angular - Collectiong restful api response of different format

Tags: angular

Currently, I am using Angular-11.

How do I collect this JSON api response in Angular. I am confused about this format (user, roles, message):

```
{
  "message": "Successfully Logged In.",
  "error": false,
  "code": 200,
  "results": {
    "user": {
      "id": 2,
      "username": "Lamptey",
      "email": "lamptey@gmail.com",
      "mobile_number": "2318056785544",
      "first_name": "Lamptey",
      "last_name": "Akwetey",
      "email_verified_at": null,
      "active": 1,
      "created_at": "2021-05-24T07:27:41.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-05-26T19:02:30.000000Z",
      "roles": [{
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Supervisor",
        "guard_name": "api",
        "created_at": "2021-05-24T07:02:14.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-05-24T07:02:14.000000Z",
        "pivot": {
          "model_id": 2,
          "role_id": 4,
          "model_type": "App\\Models\\User"
        }
      }],
      "employee": null
    },
    "access_token": {
      "id": "cggfgfgfggggggggggggggg",
      "user_id": 2,
      "client_id": 1,
      "name": "iHRM",
      "scopes": [],
      "revoked": false,
      "created_at": "2021-05-26 20:02:30",
      "updated_at": "2021-05-26 20:02:30",
      "expires_at": "2021-08-25T19:02:30.000000Z"
    },
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_at": "2021-08-25 20:02:30"
  }
}
```

For instance,  If I have baseUrl = "localhost:8888/myapp"; api/login'. How do I do the user (post to login) and also user and roles detail

Thanks

Comment: No shortage of documentation on how to do this: https://angular.io/guide/http. Try doing some research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `REST` endpoint with `HttpClient` module, like this:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

...

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

...
let endpoint = 'your_endpoint';

this.http.get(endpoint).subscribe((response: any) => {
  console.log('Response: ', response);
}, (error:any) => {
  console.log('ERROR: ', error);
});

this.http.put(endpoint, {
  // This is the request body
}).subscribe((response: any) => {
  console.log('Response: ', response);
}, (error:any) => {
  console.log('ERROR: ', error);
});

this.http.post(endpoint, {
  // This is the request body
}).subscribe((response: any) => {
  console.log('Response: ', response);
}, (error:any) => {
  console.log('ERROR: ', error);
});

this.http.delete(endpoint).subscribe((response: any) => {
  console.log('Response: ', response);
}, (error:any) => {
  console.log('ERROR: ', error);
});
```

Comment: @NedadMilosavljevic - Pardon me if it embarasses you. If I have  baseUrl = "http://localhost:8888/myapp";   api/login'.  How do I do the user (post to login) and also user and roles detail

Comment: I updated my answer. You can send all requests methods with `HttpClient`. You can send `post` request and you can add request body.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the interface for this response:

```
export interface Data {
  field1: string
  field2: ....
   .....
}
```

then you can call your endpoint with a specified type:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

...

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

makeCall() {
  return this.http.get<Data>(`your_url`)
}
```